# Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "." found

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I faced this problem:

> Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "." found in the end of the program.

```
program odin;
uses crt;
var res,ans:byte;
begin
clrscr;
writeln('Загружаю названия ресторанов поблизости...');
    delay(5000);
writeln('Список ресторанов:');
    delay(1000);
writeln('1.McSonalds');
    delay(1000);
writeln('2.KDC');
    delay(1000);
writeln('3.Wobulimans');
    delay(1000);
writeln('4.Homelytown');
    delay(5000);
writeln('Выберите интересующий вас ресторан: ');
        readln(res);
if (res=1) then
begin
            writeln('Здравствуйте. Это ресторан - McSonalds .');
            writeln('М Е Н Ю:');
            writeln('1.Суп <<Импровизация>>');
            writeln('2.Чай <<Быстрый>>');
            writeln('3.Кофе <<Лаваццо>>');
            writeln('4.Салат <<Вашингтон>>');
            writeln('Выберите интересующее вас блюдо: ');
                readln(ans);
    delay(1000);
            writeln('Загружаю КБЖУ...');
    delay(4000);
    readln;
    case ans of
    1: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 230');
            writeln('Белки: 10');
            writeln('Жиры: 45');
            writeln('Углеводы: 43');
            readln;
        end;
    2: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 13');
            writeln('Белки: 0');
            writeln('Жиры: 0');
            writeln('Углеводы: 3');
            readln;
        end;
    3: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 45');
            writeln('Белки: 3');
            writeln('Жиры: 5');
            writeln('Углеводы: 7');
            readln;
        end;
    4: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 147');
            writeln('Белки: 10');
            writeln('Жиры: 34');
            writeln('Углеводы: 28');
            readln;
        end;
end;
    if (res=2) then
begin
            writeln('Здравствуйте. Это ресторан - KDC .');
    delay(4000);
            writeln('М Е Н Ю:');
    delay(1000);
            writeln('1.Суп <<Кипиш>>');
            writeln('2.Чай <<Супер>>');
            writeln('3.Кофе <<Якоб>>');
            writeln('4.Салат <<Нью-Йорк>>');
    delay(4000);
            writeln('Выберите интересующее вас блюдо: ');
                readln(ans);
    delay(1000);
            writeln('Загружаю КБЖУ...');
            readln;
    delay(4000);

    case ans of
    1: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 180');
            writeln('Белки: 10');
            writeln('Жиры: 38');
            writeln('Углеводы: 57');
            readln;
        end;
    2: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 13');
            writeln('Белки: 0');
            writeln('Жиры: 1');
            writeln('Углеводы: 3');
            readln;
        end;
    3: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 53');
            writeln('Белки: 7');
            writeln('Жиры: 5');
            writeln('Углеводы: 3');
            readln;
        end;
    4: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 120');
            writeln('Белки: 10');
            writeln('Жиры: 43');
            writeln('Углеводы: 19');
            readln;
        end;
end;
    if (res=3) then
        begin
            writeln('Здравствуйте. Это ресторан - Wobulimans .');
    delay(4000);
            writeln('М Е Н Ю:');
    delay(1000);
            writeln('1.Суп <<Вулкан>>');
            writeln('2.Чай <<Спокойный>>');
            writeln('3.Кофе <<Мачи-коро>>');
            writeln('4.Салат <<Саймон>>');
    delay(4000);
            writeln('Выберите интересующее вас блюдо: ');
                readln(ans);
    delay(1000);
            writeln('Загружаю КБЖУ...');
            readln;
    delay(4000);
    case ans of
    1: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 230');
            writeln('Белки: 8');
            writeln('Жиры: 78');
            writeln('Углеводы: 13');
            readln;
        end;
    2: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 10');
            writeln('Белки: 0');
            writeln('Жиры: 0');
            writeln('Углеводы: 4');
            readln;
        end;
    3: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 45');
            writeln('Белки: 12');
            writeln('Жиры: 5');
            writeln('Углеводы: 10');
            readln;
        end;
    4: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 134');
            writeln('Белки: 10');
            writeln('Жиры: 45');
            writeln('Углеводы: 43');
            readln;
        end;
end;
    if (res=4) then
begin
            writeln('Здравствуйте. Это ресторан - Homelytown .');
    delay(4000);
            writeln('М Е Н Ю:');
    delay(1000);
            writeln('1.Суп <<Сырный>>');
            writeln('2.Чай <<Крепкий>>');
            writeln('3.Кофе <<Красный закаm>>');
            writeln('4.Салат <<Ностальгия>>');
    delay(4000);
            writeln('Выберите интересующее вас блюдо: ');
                readln(ans);
    delay(1000);
            writeln('Загружаю КБЖУ...');
            readln;
    delay(4000);
    case ans of
    1: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 340');
            writeln('Белки: 13');
            writeln('Жиры: 35');
            writeln('Углеводы: 23');
            readln;
        end;
    2: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 0');
            writeln('Белки: 0');
            writeln('Жиры: 5');
            writeln('Углеводы: 3');
            readln;
        end;
    3: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 50');
            writeln('Белки: 10');
            writeln('Жиры: 25');
            writeln('Углеводы: 19');
            readln;
        end.
    4: begin
            writeln('КБЖУ(100г продукта):');
            writeln('Калорийность: 210');
            writeln('Белки: 10');
            writeln('Жиры: 45');
            writeln('Углеводы: 54');
            readln;
        end;
end;
   end.
```

I'm just a beginner, so please, help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205196/

Comment: You have `end.` twice. You need it once. Fix that, and then you also have four missing `end`. You problems will disappear once you start indenting you code properly.

Answer (score 1):

On the last line and on the last end of case 3 you have 'end.' instead of 'end;' Change the dot into a semicolon and that should fix it

NOTE: The error litterally says. 'EXPECTED a ";" FOUND a "." which means it found a "." on the place where it is supposed to have a ";"

Comment: Could you give the line where the error occurs also update your code in the post as that was an error anyway

Comment: @TomTruyen This is but part of the story. There are a ton of missing `end` statements also.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I didn't look that far into it.

Comment: It's all a bit pointless. Asker needs to learn how to work this stuff out. I mean, reading the error messages is a basic requirement. If asker won't read error messages, what hope is there?

Comment: True but like he said he is new to it. He might not understand what a syntax error is

Comment: formating code so that begin/ends and case/ends are alligned and code inside begin ends is indented does help to sort out this kind of errors. This error particulary happens very often ehne there are some missing ends or extra begins.